# Getting "No route matches [PATCH]" error even though method and route exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, routes

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I have this in my “./app/views/user_objects/_form.html.erb” page

```
<%= form_for(@user_object, :url => url_for(:controller => 'user_objects', :action => 'create')) do |f| %>
    …
    <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I click on the “Save” button on this page, I get the following error …

```
F, [2016-03-07T12:01:15.816006 #1335] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/user_objects"):
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:221:in `call'
  puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:561:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.0.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I don’t know why I get this.  I have this method defined in my controller …

```
  # POST /user_objects
  # POST /user_objects.json
  def create
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @date = Date.strptime(user_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
    @mysql_formatted_date = @date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    @user_object = Userobject.find_by_user_id_and_object_id_and_day(@current_user.id, user_object_params[:object_id], @mysql_formatted_date)
    if (@user_object.nil?) then
      @user_object = Userobject.new(user_object_params)
      @user_object.day = @date
      @user_object.user_id = @current_user.id
    else
      @user_object.total = user_object_params[:total]
    end
    # Render the response
    @objects = object.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_object.save
        puts "Saving data" 
        format.html { render :action => 'index', :id => @user_object, notice: 'Information saved successfully.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @user_object }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
        format.json { render json: @user_object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So what gives?  I have this defined in my config/routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user_objects do
    get :find_by_user_object_and_day, on: :collection
    get :find_totals, on: :collection
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
<%= form_for(@user_object, :url => url_for(:controller => 'user_objects', :action => 'create')) do |f| %>
```

which works fine when you're creating the object initially, but doesn't work when you want to update the object.

change it to

```
<%= form_for @user_object do |f| %>
```

and add

```
resources :user_objects, except: :update do
  member do
    patch :create
    put :create
  end
end
```

to routes.rb

and than figure out in the #create action in user_objects controller the distinguish a create from an update action.

Again, what you're doing is against Rails convention and not advisable.

Comment: I replaced hte line with what you suggested, and got the error, "undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fc37fff37b0>:0x007fc37935fb30>, Did you mean?  simple_format"

Comment: Forgive me, copy&paste error, I've edited the answer.

Comment: How does this line allow me to submit both types of actions to the same method in the controller?  I tried the above and it doesn't submit both to the same method.

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying that it use create in the form and then trying to use that form to update.

take a look at this line:

```
<%= form_for(@user_object, :url => url_for(:controller => 'user_objects', :action => 'create')) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding whta the solution would be.  I want the form to always submit to the "create" action, whether someone is editing or adding a new object.

Comment: @Dave no. you want to submit to the update action when someone is editing and the create action when adding a new object.

Comment: I realize what I'm asking for is unconventional, but humor me, how would I submit both types of actions to the same method in the controller?

Comment: You shouldn't submit to the same controller action for both. They are different routes that represent different actions. One is a post and one is a patch. The error is telling you that.

You can either use two separate form partials or refactor your form partial so it works with both routes. Those are your best options.

Comment: So you are saying what I'm asking is impossible?  I'm a novice at Rails, but it seems Rails is more sophisticated than that and that you are wrong, dead wrong.  But if I can't find a solution, I'll swallow my words and accept your answer.

Comment: No--it's possible. It's just not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using resources in your routes file, rails is automatically assigning the request type to the actions (CRUD). So create is a post and update is and put (or patch). If you want to do both in the same action you will have to create a new method in your controller that handles both cases and then submit your form to that route which needs to be defined in the routes file.

Comment: You say, "you will have to create a new method in your controller that handles both cases ", and yes I have already done taht, but when you say "submit your form to that route which needs to be defined in the routes file", taht is exactly the question, I'm asking.  How do I do that?  A code example would be really great here.